# How to say "In order to keep a smooth reading" in a good academic way?

Tags: vocabulary, syntactic-analysis, academia

I'm currently writing my (math) thesis. Some properties of the objects I'm studying are used often and are relatively elementary. So, I would like to state them once and then avoiding referring to them each time I need as I believe it would disrupt the reading. So, I have the following sentences at some point:

> We recall useful properties of A and B. **In order to keep a smooth reading**, we use these properties in most of the proofs below without explicitly referring to them.

The bold part feels like bad english to me, so I'm wondering what would be a better formulation for it.

Comment: A "better" approach might be to change your opinion. Google Books claims *thousands* of written instances of [*a smooth reading,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+smooth+reading%22) and I see nothing wrong with your cited text. But if you really don't like it, just switch to something like ***for** [the sake of] **clarity** [and simplicity]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, then I'll keep it as is unless something much better appears as an answer. I thought about "for the sake of clarity/simplicity" but, unless the meaning of "clarity" isn't clear to me, I'm not sure this is the intended purpose. Regarding, simplicity, I believe that "for the sake of simplicity" has a different meaning in maths (basically you make more assumptions to have less technical problems). Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Have you thought of asking over at some math.SE, where they might have a better handle on what the usual English wording or even conventions are for this?

Comment: @Mitch I haven't and this is a good point. If it is ok for this community, I will first leave this post as is and if nothing comes out of it, I'll reask in math.SE.

Comment: Why bother with the phrase at all? I would simply write "We will use these properties in most of the proofs below without explicitly referring to them."

Comment: @Derek That's also a good point, but my advisor tends to appreciate motivated decisions.

Comment: You can also say *in order to keep* ***to*** *smooth reading*. Or you can switch the wording around: *in order to keep reading smooth*.

Comment: For myself, I'd simplify the qualifier into *"..for legibility we will use these properties in most proofs without explicit reference..."* - and in specific I'd do it this way for legibility's sake.

Comment: Your original phrase looks very odd to me (native BrE speaker, postgraduate degrees in mathematics). If you really have to give a reason, how about: "To avoid repetition..."?

Comment: I was about to post exactly what Derek did, when I saw he already had. How does your advisor tending to appreciate motivated decisions change that, or your original Question?

In any case, how is this not all about choice, proof-reading or writing style?